# manage 3 domains in cPanel : email, redirect to AWS and to another domain

Tags: email, dns, amazon-web-services, cpanel

I have those domains (fictious names) :

> - www.myponey.ca
> - www.unicorn.ca
> - www.unicorn.com

All active in cPanel Accelerated 2. The main domain in cPanel is www.myponey.ca and what I'd like to do is:

> 1. being able to use emails in the cPanel for the first 2 domains
> 2. having www.unicorn.ca point to a server on Amazon Web Services (AWS)
> 3. creating a subdomain like magical.unicorn.ca that point to a server on AWS
> 4. redirect www.unicorn.com to www.unicorn.ca

I started with creating add-on domains but ran into many problems, I'm not sure this is the right way to go now. Not even sure if this can be done in cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my hosting company, we we're able to solve all issues. Had to add 1 more add-on domain, had to change the MX Entry in email and some changes in Advanced Zone Editor for some of the domains. If anyone is having the same problem, contact your hosting company! It can all be done